# Backrefence syntax in powershell's sed

Tags: powershell, sed, find-and-replace

How do I back reference a capture group in powershell's sed? I can't seem to find the syntax for it.

IE I expect `echo "hello" | sed "s|(h)ello|world\1|"` to output `worldh`, but instead I get the following error:

```
sed : sed.exe: -e expression #1, char 18: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
At line:1 char:16
+ echo "hello" | sed "s|(h)ello|world\1|"
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (sed.exe: -e exp...' command's RHS:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Comment: Powershell does not have sed. If you are doing this in powershell then you are using a windows port of sed.

Comment: @EBGreen That is possible. I'm definitely using sed in powershell, but if sed doesn't exist in powershell that would explain why Im seeing so little documentation on it

Comment: Do a get-Command sed | fl * and you can track down where it is running from. Have you installed cygwin at any point?

Comment: Not knowing what version of sed you are running try : ***echo "hello" | sed -r "s|(h)ello|world\1|"***

Comment: As a bonus, here is the native powershell way to do the same thing: ***'hello' -replace '(h)ello', 'world$1'***